# recursive summation of N/(2N - 1)

Tags: java, recursion

For a positive integer N, I want the summation of `1/1 + 2/3 + ... + N/(2N-1)`.

My recursive `Sum` method is stuck on an infinite loop and I don't know why. When printing out variables I noticed that `first` (my parameter) is increasing. The statement that increments `value` is never reached.

```
public double Sum(double first) {

    if (first > 1) {
     System.out.println("first :" + first);
     value  +=   first / ( Sum(2*first - 1) + Sum(first-1) );
     System.out.println("val: " + value);
     return value;
    }

   if (first <= 1) {
       return 1;
    }
  else {
      return value;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make the recursive calls in the `if (first > 1)` branch.

The first of these recursive calls is to `Sum(2*first - 1)`; this, and the other recursive call, must be fully evaluated before `value` can be incremented. The argument there is also `> 1`, so you will keep on entering the same branch, making these recursive calls infinitely (or, at least, until you exceed the maximum value stored in a double).

---

If you want to do it recursively starting at `N`, you don't need the two recursive calls anyway:

```
public double Sum(int first) {
  if (first <= 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return first / (2.0 * first - 1) + Sum(first - 1);
  }
}
```

Then evaluate it by calling `Sum(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
value += first / (2*first - 1) + Sum(first-1);
```